# EditText does not get centered in its view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm writing an app that will always be used in Portrait. I have an "EditView" in which I want to occupy the full width of the screen but center the text in the screen (horizontal). Normally, in the manifest file you just plug the android:layout_gravity="center" and that's it. But it doesn't work at all (Stays on left) and I've tried just about all the combinations of match_parent/wrap_content for the width and height. Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="2" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <EditText
          android:id="@+id/text_video_title"
          style="@style/StyleVideoTitle"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:ems="10"
          android:inputType="none"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="@string/video_title" >

       </EditText>


       <VideoView
          android:id="@+id/videoView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" 
          android:layout_gravity="center" >
       </VideoView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
          android:baselineAligned="false" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1">
          <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView" 

             android:layout_height="match_parent" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:numColumns="3"
             android:layout_gravity="center">
          </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that if I change in the EditView the android:layout_width to "wrap_content", I get a text that is almost centered but it is not really. Also, I checked the @string/video_title and there are no leading or trailling spaces that would mess up the alignment.

And the style that I use style="@style/text_video_title" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="StyleVideoTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any idea how I can center (left to right) that string?  I have the same behavior on the emulator and a real device (gingerbread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_gravity` in the `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks very much Zabri. You fixed my problem in one sentence. That was simple but I did not see it at all.